# How to add values of an array to one matrix's column?

Tags: java

I'm doing some example in Java try to add values of an array to the matrix's column. But the problem is I don't know why the matrix didn't change:

for example: 
input:

```
array  = 1 1 1 1 

matrix = 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0
```

output should be:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0
```

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int col = 0, row = 0;
    int [][]a = new int[4][4];
    int[]temp = new int[4];
    for( row = 0 ; row<4;row++)
    {
        for( col = 0 ; col<4 ;col++)
        {
            a[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(row = 0; row<4;row++)
    {
        temp[row] = 1;
    }

    while(col<4)
    {
        for(row = 0; row <4; row++)
        {
            a[row][col] = temp[row];

        }
        row+=1;
    }
    for( row = 0 ; row<4;row++)
    {
        System.out.print(temp[row] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for( row = 0 ; row<4;row++)
    {
        for( col = 0 ; col<4 ;col++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[row][col]+ "   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

For now, the matrix is still zeros. Is there any otherway to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
 while(col<4)
{
    for(row = 0; row <4; row++)
    {
        a[row][col] = temp[row];

    }
    row+=1;
}
```

to

```
    col = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        a[row][col] = temp[row];
    }
```

Comment: @TâmLươngMinh make sure you accept the answer as a right one :)

Comment: oh I forgot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, here:

```
   while(col<4)
    {
        for(row = 0; row <4; row++)
        {
            a[row][col] = temp[row];

        }
        row+=1;
    }
```

You are adding row+=1, but the loop is about cols. That's could be one of the reasons of unexpected behaviour.

At the same time, as you are using the same iterator that was used before - this loop is never executed. (col is already == 4 from the firs loop)

Comment: Actually, this while never executes, because the `col` is never less than 4.. Make sure to reset `col` value to 0 or something else you want

Comment: MrHolal gave me the solution, thanks for giving me instruction :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will know which column you have to replace with the values specified in the array ( in your case, it is the 1st column )

Anyways the value in your `while` loop is incorrect since you have used the same local variable `col` which is already at 4 from your earlier for loop, so your while loop never executes. 
Replacing it with some changes to the values of variables like so-

```
       int foo = 0;  //initialize a new variable for the loop cycles
       col = 0;      // set the value of col to the column you want to replace
       while (foo < 4)
        {
            for(row = 0; row <4; row++)
            {
                a[row][col] = temp[row];

            }
            row+=1;
            foo++;
        }
```

should solve it.